# How to change a list of characters into ASCII form?

Tags: python, list, integer, character, decimal

I'd like to know how to turn a *list* of characters into their *ascii* form (a = 97, x = 120, etc). I have tried making each individual item into decimal form by using a loop, but I wonder if there is a better way to do so.
I have written this so far, but this doesn't seem to work.

```
x = input().lower()
message = list( x ) 
messageInt = []
i = 0
while True:
        messageInt.append( ord(message([i]))
        i += 1
print messageInt
```

How can I get my code to result in this
`[ 101, 120, 101, 97, 109, 112, 108, 101 ]`
If the input was the word "example".

Comment: `a_list = [ord(i) for i in input().lower()]`

Comment: this is an infinite loop do you realize that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are:

```
s = "string here"
a = list(map(ord,list(s.lower())))
```

`a` contains the list of numbers.

To make something similar to your question you'd do this:

```
print(list(map(ord,list(input().lower()))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

because you want to convert a string to its integer equivalent , so you need to use `int()` function which will convert the string to its integer equivalent ,but you want to convert all the elements of a list , so you can use map function which takes two parameters function and the iterator then it will apply the function to all the elements of iterator .

If you are using python2 then return a list and if you are using python 3 then it will return a map object so you can convert this map object to a list by applying `list()`

```
`x = input().lower()'
'message = list(x)'
'messageInt = list(map(int,message))'
```